# How delete Extjs trial icon in Extjs-6?

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-cmd, extjs6

I'm developing a web application using [Extjs-6](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0). I'm using [sencha cmd-6](http://docs.sencha.com/cmd) to create base application. When I create a `panel` it shown as follow:

[image]

**How can I delete Extjs trial icon at *top-right corner* of panel**?

Comment: Consider using GPL version.

Comment: I don't think this kind of question should get  automatically donwvote

Answer (score 3):

You should run the command

```
sencha app upgrade /path/to/my/extjs
```

like mention in this [thread](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?286637-Watermark-showing-quot-Ext-JS-Trial-quot-in-panels)

Answer (score 2):

Just download [GPL version of ExtJS 6](https://www.sencha.com/legal/gpl/) and build your app using this ExtJS 6 package like this:

```
sencha -sdk /path/to/ext6 generate app MyApp /path/to/my-app
```

More information about [GPL license for ExtJS](https://www.sencha.com/legal/open-source-faq/).

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't do that.

It breaks Terms and Conditions of Use.

https://www.sencha.com/legal/#Sencha_Ext_JS

> Trial Licensing A trial download is available for Sencha Ext JS
>   effective for 30 days and governed by the Sencha SDK Software License
>   Agreement. You cannot commence development of an application under
>   GPLv3 license and later convert to a commercial license. You cannot
>   develop during a trial period and continue development beyond that
>   period (30 days).

Comment: "You cannot commence development of an application under GPLv3 license and later convert to a commercial license". Actually you can. The point is if they don't sell you the commercial license. So they should have written: "We will not sell you the license if you try to switch from GPL to commercial licence", what anyways is a very mean, dumb and stupid policy (in my opinion).

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to delete trial icon. To remove that icon you need to purchase it and replace the frame work file with purchased framework file.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard. Because such "Trial" icons and also other kind of logical conditions like "if trial then put some Trial text here and there" placed in many different places. You will never know did you remove all of them or not.

So better do as suggested in other answers - buy or use gpl.

UPD. But if you want to try you can play with `ExtJs/cmd/sencha.cfg` file

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple but not correct.

On linux box type:

1. cd /-your app folder-/ext
2. find . -name "*.scss" | xargs grep -il ext-trial

you should get:

```
./ext/classic/theme-neutral/sass/src/panel/Panel.scss
./ext/classic/theme-neutral/sass/src/window/Window.scss
./ext/classic/theme-base/sass/etc/all.scss
./ext/classic/theme-base/sass/src/Component.scss
./ext/modern/theme-base/sass/etc/all.scss
./ext/modern/theme-base/sass/src/viewport/Viewport.scss
```

3. edit each of these files and remove all the block matching "ext-trial"
4. repeat 2 and 3 with "ext-beta" and "ext-watermark"
5. sencha app refresh;

or

6. use GPL version

Comment: I may have a simplier anwser : just edit `ext/classic/theme-base/sass/etc/all.scss` and set `$ext-trial` to `false`. This file is maybe regenerated but for now it works for me.